# How can I set a specific email to use?

Tags: android

I want to create some code in my sign up activity which let people use only one email adress with a specific domain.

For example user on the registration form can use only email which domain is 
: @ubu.com

otherwise people can not register with other email.

Thank you.

Comment: You'd want to verify that on the server side and reject any signup from another domain.  You can do that on the client side as well as an optimization, but for security you should always validate parameters on the server when sending data to it.

Comment: no i just want that user can only register with email that ends with this domain @ubu.com

Comment: Yes, and that's how you'd do it.

Comment: how i can code it

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming you want to validated the email domain in **Client End** only.

Use a regular expression. This expression validates any given string as email and checks if it's domain name matches **.edu.com**

```
"^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@" + "(edu\\.com)$"
```

Test method:

```
 public boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        String regEx = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                + "(edu\\.com)$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

Now validate each email address before signing up.

Comment: you are shooting the fly with a cannon here.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What's wrong if the user wants to validate the email in client end? The requirement is to allow and proceed with the specific email domain only.

Comment: you split the string into prefix and domain part and compare. That's it. You regex is neither needed nor flexible for that.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski That's a bad approach to handle complex email address. Splitting the string wont validate any invalid chars as well as an incorrect email with a valid domain. My solution works in all circumstances. Anyways, you simply put a negative vote just because my solution is complex.

Comment: Syntax validation is one thing, allowance is other. Your approach is bad because is not scallable and if I would like to have 10 allowed domains not one, then this approach is simply useless. But yes, dream on it's master solution and it is down-voted it because it's advanced not because it is bad.